# Send Form Results to email account

Tags: html, forms, contacts

I would like to send the input data of this form to an email account. I have tried adding form action and mailto but it just opens my outlook up with that account in the send to box.

Here is the form **CODE**.

```html
<div class="gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper" id="gform_wrapper_4">
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_4" action="/proposal/">
    <div class="gform_body">
      <ul id="gform_fields_4" class="gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below">
        <li id="field_4_1" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
          <label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_1">Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
          <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_1" id="input_4_1" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>
        </li>
        <li id="field_4_2" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
          <label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_2">Company/Organization<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
          <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_2" id="input_4_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>
        </li>
        <li id="field_4_8" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
          <label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_8">Website<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
          <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_8" id="input_4_8" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>
        </li>
        <li id="field_4_4" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
          <label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_4">Phone<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
          <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_phone"><input name="input_4" id="input_4_4" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>
        </li>
        <li id="field_4_5" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
          <label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_5">Email<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
          <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_email">
            <input name="input_5" id="input_4_5" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="field_4_6" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
          <label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_6">Your Message</label>
          <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_textarea"><textarea name="input_6" id="input_4_6" class="textarea medium" aria-invalid="false" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></div>
        </li>
        <li id="field_4_7" class="gfield gform_hidden field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><input name="input_7" id="input_4_7" type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" aria-invalid="false" value=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gform_footer top_label"> <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_4" class="gform_button button" value="Submit Form" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_4&quot;]){return false;}  window[&quot;gf_submitting_4&quot;]=true;  " onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_4&quot;]){return false;} window[&quot;gf_submitting_4&quot;]=true;  jQuery(&quot;#gform_4&quot;).trigger(&quot;submit&quot;,[true]); }">
      <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="is_submit_4" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_submit" value="4">
      <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_unique_id" value="">
      <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="state_4" value="WyJbXSIsImZkMjhiMWNmMmIxMjkzNDczNWEwMDUwYjY4NjUyMjUzIl0=">
      <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_target_page_number_4" id="gform_target_page_number_4" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_source_page_number_4" id="gform_source_page_number_4" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="gform_field_values" value="">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You need backend (server side) code to receive the form and email it. You can't email directly from the browser.

Comment: That is what we were thinking too. Thanks a lot for the info